# load data from s3 to mysql aurora

Tags: mysql

Below is the code I am writing to insert the data from txt file into mysql table .
my text file contains data as :

```
G121|CON|20000374|PRD|145022|1||||||
G121|PRM|CI|20000375|20180927000000|
G121|CON|20000375|PDG|2000023|0|||||
G121|TXT|20000375|PRD
G121|TXT|20000375|PRD
G121|TXT|20000375|PRD
```

now the problem is when in 4th row data is not found for columns it throws error:

here is the load data code :

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3-file path'
 INTO TABLE `dbname`.`table_name`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 (STORE_NO, RECORD_TYPE, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, COL_6, COL_7, COL_8, COL_9, COL_10, COL_11);
```

i have tried with user variables as well but no positive results.
do i need to have all the columns in file according to mysql?

Comment: "do i need to have all the columns in file according to mysql?" Well technically it isn't valid CSV "syntax" from line 4 so i indeed assume you need to add those.. What error did you get?

Comment: its a txt file ... and i am getting error "doesn't contain data for all columns"..and i cannot add manually in txt file.

Answer (score 1):

User defined variables work for me. Try something like this

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(
STORE_NO varchar(20), RECORD_TYPE varchar(20), COL_3 varchar(20), COL_4 varchar(20), COL_5 varchar(20), 
COL_6 varchar(20), COL_7 varchar(20), COL_8 varchar(20), COL_9 varchar(20), COL_10 varchar(20), COL_11 varchar(20)
)
;

 LOAD DATA infile 'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
 INTO TABLE t
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 (@STORE_NO, @RECORD_TYPE, @COL_3, @COL_4, @COL_5, @COL_6, @COL_7, @COL_8, @COL_9, @COL_10, @COL_11)
 set store_no = @store_no,
      record_type = @record_type,
      col_3 = if(length(@col_3) = 0 ,null,@col_3),
          col_4 = if(length(@col_4) = 0 ,null,@col_4),
          col_5 = if(length(@col_5) = 0 ,null,@col_5),
          col_6 = if(length(@col_6) = 0 ,null,@col_6),
          col_7 = if(length(@col_7) = 0 ,null,@col_7),
          col_8 = if(length(@col_8) = 0 ,null,@col_8),
          col_9 = if(length(@col_9) = 0 ,null,@col_9),
          col_10 = if(length(@col_10) = 0 ,null,@col_10),
          col_11 = if(length(@col_11) = 0 ,null,@col_11)
;
 select * from t;

+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| STORE_NO | RECORD_TYPE | COL_3    | COL_4    | COL_5          | COL_6 | COL_7 | COL_8 | COL_9 | COL_10 | COL_11 |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| G121     | CON         | 20000374 | PRD      | 145022         | 1     | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| G121     | PRM         | CI       | 20000375 | 20180927000000 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| G121     | CON         | 20000375 | PDG      | 2000023        | 0     | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| G121     | TXT         | 20000375 | PRD      | NULL           | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| G121     | TXT         | 20000375 | PRD      | NULL           | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| G121     | TXT         | 20000375 | PRD      | NULL           | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Nice find + 1.. i assume this also works when you modify to `IS NULL` check like so `col_3 = if(@col_3 is null,null,@col_3)` ? Which seams to be better fit in mine option to indicate missing values.

Comment: @ Raymond Nijland - nope the missing fields are populated with nulls but those where the delimiters exist are populated with an empty string.